# Owners who have rejected or who haven't reacted to a safe tx

Tags: transactions, gnosis-safe, safe-core, safe

I am building a notification system which will allow the owners who have not yet reacted(approved/rejected) the tx notify them to take action against a tx.
There is a way to get who have approved the tx(https://github.com/safe-global/safe-core-sdk/tree/main/packages/protocol-kit#getownerswhoapprovedtx) but no way to check who rejected or who are yet to react to the tx.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, there are no direct methods to track who rejected transactions or who is pending approval, however there are still ways to get that information.

When an owner rejects a transaction, a new empty transaction is created in the safe with the same transaction nonce. You can use this to count all the owners who have rejected it. (This is used so that other owners can override the rejection of a single owner, by approving the empty transaction.)

For those who havent approved or rejected yet, you can simply subtract from the total amount of owners those who have already reacted.

Hope it helps,
Louis